# functions assigned to function pointers in a class

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I have a program that deals with operations in polynomials. An "operator" class has a char pointer to the input string, a pointer to a function of type float (float, float) that is used to perform an operation on the arguments. Then there are a series of methods, setSymb(char *) points opChar to the argument, and points the opFunc pointer to the function that corresponds to the operator character. However when I run this method, and at the line where it assigns the function to the pointer function, there is an unhandled exception under new.cpp, when it tries to allocate memory of some sort. This confuses me a great deal.

```
#include "stckArrClassLib.h"
using namespace stacks;
using namespace conversion;

#define SIDE bool
#define LEFT 0
#define RIGHT 1

class oprt
{
public:
    typedef float (oprt::*fp)(float, float);
private:
    char *opSymb;
    fp opFunc;
    float *lOpnd;
    float *rOpnd;
    oprt *Lnext;
    oprt *Rnext;
    float rslt;
protected:
        float add(float a, float b){return a+b;};
    float mult(float a, float b){return a*b;};
    float div(float a, float b){return a/b;};
    float exp(float a, float b){return powf(a, b);};
    float par(float a, float b){return a;};
public:
    oprt (void) {opFunc=NULL;};
    oprt &setSymb(char *);
    oprt &setNext(SIDE, oprt *);
    oprt &setOpnd(SIDE, float);
    float evaluate();
    char *getSymb();
    fp getFunc();
    float *getOpnd(SIDE);
    oprt *getNext(SIDE);
};

oprt& oprt::setSymb(char *set)
{
        CArray<char, 8> opStr;
    opStr[0]=*(set), set;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<7 && (!(set[i]>='0' && set[i]<='9') && !(set[i]=='+' || set[i]=='-' || opStr[i]=='*' || set[i]=='/' || set[i]=='^' || set[i]=='(')); i++)
    opStr[i]=set[i];
    opStr[i]=0;
    if(strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, "+")==0)
            //problem is here
    opFunc=&oprt::add;
    else if(strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, "*")==0)
            //and here
    opFunc=&oprt::mult;
    else if(strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, "/")==0)
            //etc.
    opFunc=&oprt::div;
    else if(strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, "^")==0)
    opFunc=&oprt::exp;
    else if(strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, "(")==0 || strcmp((const char *)opStr.arr, ")")==0)
    opFunc=&oprt::par;
        return *this;
}

oprt& oprt::setNext(SIDE side, oprt *next)
{
    if(side==LEFT)
{
    Lnext=next;
    lOpnd=&(next->rslt);
}
else if(side==RIGHT)
{
    Rnext=next;
    rOpnd=&(next->rslt);
}
return *this;
}

float oprt::evaluate()
{
return rslt=(this->*opFunc)(*getOpnd(LEFT), *getOpnd(RIGHT));
}

char *oprt::getSymb()
{
return opSymb;
}

oprt::fp oprt::getFunc()
{
return opFunc;
}

float *oprt::getOpnd(SIDE side)
{
if(!((side==LEFT)? (Lnext==this):(Rnext==this)))
    (side==LEFT? Lnext:Rnext)->evaluate();
return (side==LEFT)? (lOpnd):(rOpnd);
}

oprt *oprt::getNext(SIDE side)
{
return (side==LEFT)? (Lnext):(Rnext);
}

oprt& oprt::setOpnd(SIDE side, float set)
{
(side==LEFT)? (*lOpnd=set):(*rOpnd=set);
return *this;
}
```

Here is the excerpt of new.cpp which is called at `opFunc=&oprt::add` in the function `oprt& oprt::setSymb(char *)`

```
extern "C" void * __cdecl _nh_malloc_dbg (
    size_t nSize,
    int nhFlag,
    int nBlockUse,
    const char * szFileName,
    int nLine
    )
{
    int errno_tmp = 0;
    void * pvBlk = _nh_malloc_dbg_impl(nSize, nhFlag, nBlockUse, szFileName, nLine, &errno_tmp);

    if ( pvBlk == NULL && errno_tmp != 0 && _errno())
    {
        errno = errno_tmp; // recall, #define errno *_errno()
    }
    return pvBlk;
}
```

The error is called when malloc is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to modify the typedef to this:

```
typedef float (oprt::*fp)(float, float);
```

You also don't want to ommit the '&' ampersand when assigning:

```
opFunc=&oprt::mult;
```

Comment: Even when I do this, it still fails. I have tried a variety of combinations of using typedefs and global functions.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked out for me, but I also had to remove getFunc() cause you are declaring it as a function pointer, but then you are defining it.
Are you sure it is crashing exactly there? How? With these errors it shouldn't compile, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I use visual c++, but at the exact moment it attempts to set assign a function to opFunc, the debugger comes pops up and says there was an unhandled exception under new.cpp, and the moment it tries allocating memory for some reason. It's so bizarre

Comment: I digress. The problem I mentioned was an issue in an old version. However there is a compiling error and the debugger says it can't make the conversion at the assignment point. Specifically it cannot convert from 'float (__thiscall oprt::* )(float,float)' to 'oprt::fp'.

Comment: Can you edit the post with the code as you have it now please?

Comment: what is shown gives the compiler error I mentioned most previously

Comment: but you did change the typedef right?

Comment: my apologies. I hadn't noticed the difference. Okay, I changed it, and it compiled successfully except for one other compiler error. Now its telling me that the call of the function pointed to by opFunc is invalid, under the definition of the evaluate function. It says that the term does not evaluate to a function of two arguments and that the expression must have a pointer to function type. I am confused as to what this means.

Comment: Could you paste the error message?
Also, did you change this:
float (*getFunc())(float, float);
for this:
float getFunc(float, float);

Comment: float getFunc(float, float) returns a floating point value. I want to return a function pointer of type (*)(float, float), AKA, 'fp' which I have done. Heres the error: 1>c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\operations\operations\operation.h(102): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
and also, in my software, when one moves the mouse over the point of error, it shows the error. In this case when I hover the mouse over opFunc in the return statement it reads: Error: must have (pointer-to-) function type.

Comment: I know, but it is declared as a function pointer, and below you define it, that should generate an error.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that, but there was no error for the declaration definition mis match. However I still changed it. Meanwhile, the evaluate function still has errors

Comment: Can you paste the error?

Comment: I did: 1>c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\operations\operations\operation.h(102): **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments**

Comment: The problem is that the type "oprt" is already a pointer, but on "getNext()" you are trying to return a pointer to it. (i.e. a pointer to a pointer)
Try these changes, this:
oprt *getNext(SIDE);
for this:
oprt getNext(SIDE);
and this:
oprt *oprt::getNext(SIDE side)
for this:
oprt oprt::getNext(SIDE side)

Comment: No offense, but that makes no sense. To start, the evaluate function doesn't even use `oprt *oprt::getNext(SIDE)`. it uses `float *oprt::getOpnd(SIDE)`. And I don't understand what you mean by type oprt is already a pointer.

Comment: Sorry! you're right. I am dont have a compiler here. The problem now is when you call opFunc() change this:
opFunc(*getOpnd(LEFT), *getOpnd(RIGHT));
for this:
(this->*opFunc)(*getOpnd(LEFT), *getOpnd(RIGHT));

Comment: well, it compiles now. Could you explain why this works? And now that it runs, it turns out it has the same run error I mentioned at the very beginning of the post.

Comment: In some diagnostics I ran, the compiler doesn't consider opFunc to be a pointer, ie, when I write *opFunc, it gives an error saying that operand of * must be a pointer.

Comment: If it is at runtime, this might be trying to use an invalid object:
(side==LEFT? Lnext:Rnext)->evaluate();
You should check if Lnext or Rnext is valid before calling evaluate(). You are not initializing them to NULL on the constructor.
Other than that I would have to build the code myself and I might be wrong but I am sensing you don't appreciate my help very much.

Comment: Well, you've been pretty helpful. This is very frustrating. For some reason, at runtime, the error is at malloc of size 8 under new.cpp

Comment: There is no malloc() in the code upstairs, would you paste new.cpp or an excerpt of it?

Comment: Okay. I wrote it in the question

Comment: The problem must be on the use of CArray. Do you absolutely need to use CArray? The problem seems to be there why not just use char opStr[8].

Comment: I don't think so. I put breakpoints at these parts, specifically, opStr is compared successfully, then it attempts to assign add to opFunc, then an unhandled exception at malloc() under new.cpp

Comment: Just an idea, "add" is inline, that might create a problem with its address, try defining it below.

Comment: Do you mean defining it externally? Because I've already tried that.

Comment: Yes. I've tried that. Is there anywhere else where I could go for guidance on the internet.

Comment: You could try to ask another question, with the new changes on.

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that.